# Rails unable to change label in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

Hi I'm new to rails and formtastic.

I've built a working solution for multiple file uploads using paperclip.

In my form, when I try and change the label of the upload file it still displays 'image' even when changing to:

```
 <%= f.inputs :image, :label => false, :for => :attachments,  :as => :file %>
```

or

```
<%= f.inputs :image, :label => "This label will not display", :for => :attachments,  :as => :file %>
```

really silly problem but any help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f.inputs does not support label attribute, you should use f.input if you want hide label. Or you can bypass this and hide label via css. Something like this.

```
label[for=here_go_your_for_value] {
  display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Embarrassing but if it helps 1 other person then its worth this keeping live.

Comment: * Embarrassing for me

Comment: Nothing embarrassing here, just keep asking and learning :)